# How to prevent "collect/keep" function from flatting its result

Tags: rebol, red

```
>> a: [[1 2] "a" a [3 3]]
== [[1 2] "a" a [3 3]]
>> collect [foreach x a [if block? x [keep x]]]
== [1 2 3 3]
```

But what I want is [[1 2] [3 3]]. It seems that collect/keep would flat the result(in term of block). How to prevent it?

Comment: You can also use `parse`: `parse a [collect some [keep block! | skip]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keep/only`. FYI, `keep` has almost the same semantics as `append` (barring a few refinements) with an implicit block that `collect` provides internally: see `?? collect` for the details.